# maximum-likelihood function for the SST distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, regression, maximum-likelihood

The SST distribution is a reparametrization of $ST3$, which is the skew t-student type 3. Below is some information.

Let $Z_0 \sim ST3 (0, 1, \nu, \tau)$ and $Y = \mu + \sigma\left(\frac{Z_0 - m}{s}\right)$, where,

\begin{equation}
m = E(Z_0) = \frac{2\tau^\frac{1}{2}(\nu-\nu^{-1})}{(\tau - 1)B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
s^2 = Var(Z_0) = \frac{\tau}{\tau - 2}(\nu^2 + \nu^{-2} - 1) - m^2
\end{equation}

Hence, $Y = \mu_0 + \sigma_0Z_0$, where $\mu_0 = \mu - \frac{\sigma m}{s}$ e $\sigma_0 = \frac{\sigma}{s}$, and so $Y \sim ST3(\mu_0, \sigma_0, \nu, \tau)$ with $E(Y) = \mu$ and $Var(Y) = \sigma^2$ for $\tau > 2$. Let $Y \sim SST(\mu, \sigma, \nu, \tau) = ST3(\mu_0, \sigma_0, \nu, \tau)$ for $\tau > 2$. The pdf of the skew Student t distribution, denoted by $Y \sim SST(\mu, \sigma, \nu, \tau)$, is given by:

\begin{equation}
f_Y(y|\mu, \sigma, \nu, \tau) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{c}{\sigma_0}\left(1 + \frac{\nu^2 z^2}{\tau} \right)^{\frac{-(\tau + 1)}{2}} & \mbox{if}
& y<\mu_0 \\ \frac{c}{\sigma_0}\left(1 + \frac{z^2}{\nu^2 \tau} \right)^{\frac{-(\tau + 1)}{2}} & \mbox{if} & y\geq \mu_0 
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

for $-\infty < y < \infty$, where $-\infty < \mu < \infty$, $\sigma >0$, $\nu > 0$ and $\tau > 2$ and where $z=\frac{(y-\mu_0)}{\sigma_0}$, $\mu_0 = \mu - \frac{\sigma m}{s}$, $\sigma_0 = \frac{\sigma}{s}$ and $c = 2\nu [(1+\nu^2)B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\tau}{2}\right)\tau^{\frac{1}{2}}]^{-1}$.

Note that $E(Y) = \mu$ and $Var(Y) = \sigma^2$ and the moment based skewness and excess kurtosis of $SST(\mu, \sigma, \nu, \tau)$ are the same as for $ST3(\mu_0, \sigma_0, \nu, \tau)$, and hence the same as for $ST3(0, 1, \nu, \tau)$, depending only on $\nu$ and $\tau$.

How would the likelihood function of this distribution be expressed, according to the parameters?
It is known that the link functions for $(\mu, \sigma, \nu, \tau)$ is the $identity$, $log$, $log$, and $log-2$.

Comment: Why do you simultaneously post the same question on different forums without mentioning that? If you don't mention that, then maybe the other forum has the answer and those on this forum are then wasting their time. Why would you want to waste their time? Nothing wrong with simultaneously posting but please mention at each site where you've posted.

Comment: Should $\sigma m$ be $\sigma_m$ ?

Comment: This appears to be a non-standard definition of a skewed Student's t distribution.  Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/541338/119261.

Comment: StubbornAtom and JimB Sorry! I didn't know I couldn't post the same question on different forums. I just left it here and deleted the crossvalidated.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because with the additional substitutions, the resulting pdf is horrendously complicated and I'm not seeing what good that does you.  If you are trying to find closed-form solutions for the maximum likelihood estimators of $\mu$, $\sigma$, $\nu$, and $\tau$, then I think that no closed-form solutions exist.  Are you trying to implement a maximum likelihood estimator procedure in some software package?  If so, then mentioning that would seem essential.  Otherwise I think the best you can do is have 2 parts to the likelihood after sorting the $y$ values.